# From Ora 10 to Ora 11 Express:: unable to connect from .NET

Tags: .net, oracle

From other side, I exchange with DB using System.Data.Oracle**Client** Component.
Means that it needs Client?

Will check it out later on.. and will draw a report below.

UPD: or maybe even better to reinstall Oracle XE 11

Comment: MS SQL - are you kidding me?  Talk about a step backward... Anyway, what protocol are you using?  What does your connection string in web.config look like?

Comment: TCP/IP 1521 as usual, and the cs is in the UPD section of Q. I'm going to download  ProcessMonitor.. as I remember -1 is the environment error (Shell) and it means smth like "missing file". Suppose maybe the Path should be checked and see if ORACLE_HOME in register is correct.